# Copy a specific cell for a column

Tags: python

I'm working with a dataframe that has duplicate value, and I want to copy a cell and put in correct column.
I'm beginner with python(and new in programming) and I don't know how to solve this.

Example

| Process | type | value | PVR | Hono | Civel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | PVR | $5 | $0 | $0 | $0 |
| 123456 | Civel | $17 | $0 | $0 | $0 |
| 123456 | Hono | $2 | $0 | $0 | $0 |
| 145 | Civel | $457 | $0 | $0 | $0 |
| 8547 | Civel | $47 | $0 | $0 | $0 |
| 8547 | PVR | $88 | $0 | $0 | $0 |
| 3333 | PVR | $74 | $0 | $0 | $0 |

Output:

| Process | type | value | PVR | Hono | Civel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | PVR | $5 | $5 | $17 | $2 |
| 123456 | Civel | $17 | $5 | $17 | $2 |
| 123456 | Hono | $2 | $5 | $17 | $2 |
| 145 | Civel | $457 | $0 | $0 | $457 |
| 8547 | Civel | $47 | $88 | $0 | $47 |
| 8547 | PVR | $88 | $88 | $0 | $47 |
| 3333 | PVR | $74 | $74 | $0 | $0 |

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with your sample input and output in the text of your question, not as an image or link, so that we can better understand how to help. Images can't be copied/pasted into code editors, and cause problems for screen readers

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, `df['HONORARIOS']=df['Total Valor Perda...']` ?

Comment: This is not a very good way to organize a dataset.  The columns should not be based on the row contents.  Now, if you wanted your output to have one row per process, without the "type" field, that would be a "pivot", and is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @TimRoberts , After transformation I will remove duplicate rows and I can't use pivot now because column "Process" has duplicate values. I don't have acess to database for a clean extract, so this .csv has one row for each "type". And my ideia is transform this "type" in column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I can't use pivot now because column "Process" has duplicate values.* -- I think you misunderstand the pivot process, because this is exactly what a pivot is set up to handle.  This seems to do what you want in one line:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [123456,"PVR","$5"],
    [123456,"Civel","$17"],
    [123456,"Hono","$2"],
    [145,"Civel","$457"],
    [8547,"Civel","$47"],
    [8547,"PVR","$88"],
    [3333,"PVR","$74"]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Process','type','value'])
print(df)
df1 = df.pivot(index='Process',columns='type',values='value').fillna(0)
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   Process   type value
0   123456    PVR    $5
1   123456  Civel   $17
2   123456   Hono    $2
3      145  Civel  $457
4     8547  Civel   $47
5     8547    PVR   $88
6     3333    PVR   $74
type    Civel Hono  PVR
Process                
145      $457    0    0
3333        0    0  $74
8547      $47    0  $88
123456    $17   $2   $5
```

Comment: I don't know why I received a error on first try. But this is solution that I need.  Thank you!!!